# Why this class cannot be compiled?

Tags: java

```
public class Foo<E> implements Comparable<E> {
    E a ;
    public Foo ( E a ) {
        this.a =a;
    }
    public int compareTo ( E b ) {
        return a.compareTo ( b ) ;
    }
}
```

I do not know why these code cannot be compiled.

Comment: What is `E`, also did you check the file .java have the same name as the class ?

Answer (score 1):

Generic parameter `E` does not guaranteed to have `compareTo` method, so it will fail to compile.

If you add some constraint so `E` is guaranteed to have `compareTo` method, then it will compile.

```
public class Foo<E extends Comparable<? super E>>
```

Comment: Don't use raw types. It should be `Foo<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`.

Comment: @shmosel Edited. Thanks.